# Proof Check: Probability of choosing a specific urn when pulling a red ball.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, bayes-theorem

Question: If there are 100 balls in urns A, B and C each (300 total), and the red balls in each urn are 45, 50 and 55, respectively, and the rest being yellow. If we pull a red ball from an urn, what is the probability that it was from urn A?

My attempt:

Let $U$ be the urn, and $b$ be the ball, then we are affectively asking $P(U=A|b=r)$. My first thought is to use Bayes, then we have:

$$P(U=A|b=r)=\frac{P(B=r|U=A)P(U=A)}{P(B=r)}$$

Since half the balls are red, the denominator is $\frac{1}{2}$. If the urn is $A$, then the probability of choosing the red ball is $\frac{45}{100}$ and the probability of randomly choosing urn A is $\frac{1}{3}$, then  we have:

$$P(U=A|b=r)=\frac{\frac{45}{100}\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{3}{10}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  I'm thinking about the problem in a slightly different way.  Each red ball is equally likely to be chosen.  There are $150$ red balls in total, of which $45$ started in urn $A$.  Therefore, the probability that your ball came from urn $A$ is $\frac{45}{150}=\frac{3}{10}$.